# Hamiltonian path in $S_n$?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, symmetric-groups, hamiltonian-path

Say $S_n$ is the symmetric group. Define a graph $G$ by $G=(S_n,E)$, where there is an edge from $\sigma_1$ to $\sigma_2$ if and only if $\sigma_2=t\sigma_1$ for some transposition $t$.

**Is** there a Hamiltonian path in $G$? If yes, is there a convenient way to define such a path?

No work so far - sue me. Context: For no practical reason, thinking about an elegant implementation of the formula $$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{j=1}^n a_{j,\sigma(j)}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such Hamiltonian path exists and it can obtained just by swapping adjacent elements between two successive permutations. The procedure to generate it is called the [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm).

For example, for $S_4$, it gives the following Hamiltonian path (actually a cycle) through the $4!=24$ permutations:
$$123\color{blue}{4}\to 12\color{blue}{4}3\to  1\color{blue}{4}23\to  \color{blue}{4}1\color{red}{23}\to\\
\color{blue}{4}132\to 1\color{blue}{4}32
\to 13\color{blue}{4}2\to  \color{red}{13}2\color{blue}{4}\to\\  
312\color{blue}{4} \to 31\color{blue}{4}2\to  3\color{blue}{4}12\to  \color{blue}{4}3\color{red}{12} \to\\
 \color{blue}{4}321\to  3\color{blue}{4}21\to  32\color{blue}{4}1 \to \color{red}{32}1\color{blue}{4}\to\\  
231\color{blue}{4}\to  23\color{blue}{4}1\to 2\color{blue}{4}31\to \color{blue}{4}2\color{red}{31}\to\\  \color{blue}{4}213\to  2\color{blue}{4}13 \to 21\color{blue}{4}3\to  \color{red}{21}3\color{blue}{4}\to$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

For $S_1$ and $S_2$, this is trivial.

For $S_n$ with $n\ge 2$ apply recursion: 
Starting with the identity, a Hamiltonian path for $S_{n-1}$ allows you to walk through all $(n-1)!$ permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that map $n\mapsto n$.
More generally, if you start with any $\sigma\in S_n$, this allows you to walk through all $(n-1)!$ permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that map $n\mapsto \sigma(n)$.

To get all $n!$ elements of $S_n$, start with all permutations mapping $n\mapsto n$. Then apply $(n\,n-1)$ and walk through all permutations mapping $n\mapsto n-1$. Then apply $(n-1\,n-2)$ and walk through all permutations mapping $n\mapsto n-2$. Then ...

---

Regarding your goal with the determinant: Note that this method will cost you $O(n!)$ operations, whereas the Gauss algorithm uses only $O(n^3)$.

Comment: Yes of course it's the worst possible way to actually calculate a specific determinant; hence the "for no practical reason...". But the $\sum_\sigma$ thing can be useful theoretically; it seems at least possible that a "nice" enumeration of $S_n$ could make it easier to  apply it to prove this and that.

Comment: It will be easier for me to figure out why this works if you clarify what you mean, and what I may be misunderstanding about what you mean. We start with an enumeration  $\tau_1,\dots,\tau_k$ of the permutations that fix $n$, great. Now we follow that with $(n,n-1)\tau_1,\dots,(n.n-1)\tau_k$? I don't see why $(n,n-1)\tau_{j+1}$ should be adjacent to $(n,n-1)\tau_j$. Then in the next step are you talking about $(n-1,n-2)\tau_j$ or $(n-1,n-2)(n,n-1)\tau_j$?